# finger print reader for .net windows forms / WPF or silverlight client

Tags: c#, .net, fingerprint

We are designing a solution that will be used on an internal network.

One of the requirements is to have an extra level of security beyond a simple user name and password.

Does anyone have information about how to implement a finger print reader in a .net application?

We have Thinkpads with a finger print reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need an sdk (software development kit) to go with your hardware.  Add that to your project references and you can communicate with the device.

It has to come from the hardware vendor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which reader the Thinkpad has, so I can't give you specific information.

Have a look at the [BioApi](http://www.bioapi.org/).  They have a c# wrapper and if your device is BioApi compliant, you should be able to get it running.  (Note, I had to modify the wrapper, but it is a fine base.)

Answer (score 1):

The API can be found here:  [API](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=tvan-eapfpr)

Also  one can be found here: [Not sure on compatibility](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/page/en-us)