# Fingerprint recognition C# winforms with regard to windows 7 tablets

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, tablet, fingerprint

I've developed a databaase inventory tracking system with a seperate interface for Windows 7 tablets (E.G. Viewsonic Viewpad 10). I have implemented fingerprint reading on the desktop, however, I would like to ask if it is possible to use the tablet touchscreen interface to read the fingerprint off the user? Or will I have to implement seperate fingeprint readers for the tablets?

If it is possible, how do i go about doing it? I am developing in C# winforms 64-bit. Any .net version is fine with me.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, a touch screen is different than a [finger print reader](http://www.google.com/#q=finger+print+reader&hl=en&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=shop&ei=EDhDTtGhB9PAgQe479DRCQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=5&ved=0CFEQ_AUoBA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=bdc5873391582bfe&biw=1600&bih=1115). Touch screens are no where sensitive enough to read a person's finger print.

As far as a finger print reader API, you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277373/is-there-a-fingerprint-reader-api-sdk) (which may be a bit dated). This assumes there is a proper finger print reader hooked up.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off getting hold of actual finger print reader hardware and interfacing to it via API calls, which will likely support some form of a .NET interface or wrapper.

These .net specific Q&As might be useful:

- [fingerprint reader software using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929261/fingerprint-reader-software-using-c)
- [finger print reader for .net windows forms / WPF or silverlight client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781725/finger-print-reader-for-net-windows-forms-wpf-or-silverlight-client)