# Fingerprint recognition API for windows RT?

Tags: c#, fingerprint, windows-rt

I need to check whether there is any native API available for finger print recognition. I was looking to implement this in an application centred for windows surface tablet.

thanks

Comment: For Which language, XAML + C# ? XAML + C++ ? HTML5 + WinJS ?

Comment: Check this codeproject articles, I am not sure it will become much helpful. [A Framework in C# for Fingerprint Verification](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97590/A-Framework-in-C-for-Fingerprint-Verification) and [Fingerprint Reader Integration using the M2SYS SDK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38881/Fingerprint-Reader-Integration-using-the-M2SYS-SDK)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781725/finger-print-reader-for-net-windows-forms-wpf-or-silverlight-client